# Jackson + volley - TypeReference is abstract

Tags: android, json, jackson, android-volley

i'm trying to get from an url a simple json object (not array, just {}s), and i'm getting two errors:

```
Error:(43, 81) error: TypeReference is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Error:(36, 16) error: no suitable constructor found for JsonObjectRequest(String,<anonymous Listener<JSONObject>>,<anonymous ErrorListener>) 
constructor JsonObjectRequest.JsonObjectRequest(String,JSONObject,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) 
constructor JsonObjectRequest.JsonObjectRequest(int,String,JSONObject,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

this is my OnCreate code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    String url = getResources().getString(R.string.json_url);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(GetJsonObject(url));
}
```

and this is my JsonObject method:

```
@NonNull
    private JsonObjectRequest GetJsonObject(String url) {
        return new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        Details results = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), new TypeReference<Details>());
                        String a = response.toString();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't understand the errors, especially the TypeReference one, since i have another code (witn an jsonarray) that seems to be just like that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are mixing Jackson JSONObject and Android's built-in JSONObject, it looks like

Comment: Secondary problem... This is how you read a Jackson JSON object `mapper.readValue(response, Details.class)`

Comment: Thanks for the answers! i've changed the readvalue as you say, and all the jsonobjects are the ones from android built-ins

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now :) You are using the wrong constructor. In any case, I think my answer below is how you should approach the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**: You are missing `Method.GET` and the `JSONObject jsonObject` parameters on your `JsonObjectRequest`

Here's the constructor, notice the first and third parameters.

```
public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
```

Alternatively, this one too

```
public JsonObjectRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
```

Where'd you pass `null` to the `JSONObject` to make it a GET request.

---

You are using Volley a bit backwards, though; as-in forcing it back to a synchronous method pattern. You need to mind the callbacks.

Take this stripped down method, for example. Parameterizing the two listeners.

```
@NonNull
private JsonObjectRequest GetJsonObject(String url, Response.Listener<JSONObject> onSuccess, Response.ErrorListener onError) {
    return new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, onSuccess, onError);
}
```

It is basically the same as just making the Volley Request on its own.

Now, assuming `Details` is actually an object, not a List, as you claim. You don't use `TypeReference` for that when using Jackson.

Back to Volley, an alternative pattern is to not return a request, but instead actually start one, then have the callback go to where you need that data. Also, you were turning the `JSONObject` back into a `String` for Jackson, so you can use a `StringRequest` instead.

```
public void getJSONObject(String url, Response.Listener<String> responseListener) {

    // Just some never-changing error message. 
    final Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    };

    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(url, responseListener, errorListener);
    addToRequestQueue(req); // TODO: Need to add to a RequestQueue
}
```

And call this like so

```
public void foo(String url) {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = // etc...            

        // Can declare various listeners to do different things with the String response from the URL
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        Details result = mapper.readValue(response, Details.class);
                        // TODO: Do something with the object
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };   

        // Execution returned above, when finished with request
        getJsonObject(url, responseListener);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I've modified all the code as you suggest, i got an error response (my Toast message is showed)

Comment: i've made some changes: i call the foo method on onCreate, and the request queue is :
       StringRequest req = new StringRequest(url, responseListener, errorListener);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(req);

Comment: Sure. I just put foo there. The main point was its contents. And different people use the RequestQueue differently which is why I added the comment there.